# Table Null Column Filter Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
  <form class="col2">
    <label for="filter-online">
    Filter by Online 
  </label>
    <div class="select">
      <select id="filter-online" ng-model="vm.online" class="form-control" ng-options="online for online in vm.onlines">
        <option value="">All</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>

  <form class="col2">
    <label for="filter-productType">
    Filter by Product Type
  </label>
    <div class="select">
      <select id="filter-productType" ng-model="vm.productType" class="form-control" ng-options="productType for productType in vm.productTypes">
      <option value="">All</option>
    </select>
    </div>
  </form>

  <table style="margin-top: 30px">
    <tr ng-repeat="lim in vm.stockLimits | filter:{online:vm.online && vm.online !== '' ? vm.online : '', productType: vm.productType && vm.productType !== '' ? vm.productType : ''}">
      <td>{{lim.online}}</td>
      <td>{{lim.productType}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.onlines = ["Men", "Kids", "Ladies"];
    vm.productTypes = ["Shirt", "Shoe", "Belt", "Top"];
    vm.stockLimits = [{
      id: 1,
      online: "Men",
      productType: "Shirt"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      online: "Men",
      productType: "Shoe"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      online: "Kids",
      productType: "Belt"
    }, {
      id: 4,
      online: "Ladies",
      productType: "Top"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      online: "Kids",
      productType: null
    }]
  })
```

I want to filter the data based on filter-online & filter-productType drop down.
Online always has some data but productType can be null value. When i filter by kids, productType which has null values are not filtering properly.
I need result like below if i filter by 'Kids'.

```
Kids    Belt
Kids
```

But, i'm getting only one row 
`Kids Belt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into an issue because your filter is searching for items that *contain* an empty string. All items but `null` contain an empty string. Disable the filter by setting the property to `undefined`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="lim in vm.stockLimits | filter:{online:vm.online || undefined, productType: vm.productType || undefined}">
```

You may also want the strict option to true. This would be like so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="lim in vm.stockLimits | filter:{online:vm.online || undefined, productType: vm.productType || undefined} : true">
```

This will only include *exact* matches rather than just strings that contain the provided filter (e.g. `Top` as a filter will only match `Top` and not `Topsuit`, and `''` only matches another empty string and not any string).

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.onlines = ["Men", "Kids", "Ladies"];
    vm.productTypes = ["Shirt", "Shoe", "Belt", "Top"];
    vm.stockLimits = [{
      id: 1,
      online: "Men",
      productType: "Shirt"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      online: "Men",
      productType: "Shoe"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      online: "Kids",
      productType: "Belt"
    }, {
      id: 4,
      online: "Ladies",
      productType: "Top"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      online: "Kids",
      productType: null
    }]
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
  <form class="col2">
    <label for="filter-online">
    Filter by Online 
  </label>
    <div class="select">
      <select id="filter-online" ng-model="vm.online" class="form-control" ng-options="online for online in vm.onlines">
        <option value="">All</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>

  <form class="col2">
    <label for="filter-productType">
    Filter by Product Type
  </label>
    <div class="select">
      <select id="filter-productType" ng-model="vm.productType" class="form-control" ng-options="productType for productType in vm.productTypes">
      <option value="">All</option>
    </select>
    </div>
  </form>

  <table style="margin-top: 30px">
    <tr ng-repeat="lim in vm.stockLimits | filter:{online:vm.online || undefined, productType: vm.productType || undefined}">
      <td>{{lim.online}}</td>
      <td>{{lim.productType}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to write custom filter function instead of using inline filter function? I'm new to front end framework. It would be helpful if i get custom filter function. I felt best practice is to move function to controller and call the custom filter function from html template.

Comment: Yes, of course you can make your own filter! You can find documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter). It will not be in your controller, but declared as a filter that is part of your module.